# No longer runs 'atlassian-confluence-5.10.8' on localhost:809 using macOS 11.5.1

Tags: hibernate, java-8, localhost, confluence, macos-big-sur

Have been running for many years a local version of Atlassian Confluence 5.10.8 using on localhost:8091 using:

```
macOS (Big Sur 11.5.1)
```

with:

```
java version "1.8.0_202-ea"
```

After rebooting (11.08.21) macOS I can no longer run Atlassian Confluence.

Was planning to migrate to the cloud version but now stuck!

Errors:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is net.sf.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

> type Exception report
>
> message Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested
> exception is net.sf.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot
> open connection
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
> from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
> Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
> net.sf.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open
> connection
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:473)
> org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
> sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.getTransaction(Unknown Source)
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427)
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
> com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.findById(Unknown Source)
> com.atlassian.seraph.service.rememberme.DefaultRememberMeService.getRememberMeCookieAuthenticatedUsername(DefaultRememberMeService.java:49)
> com.atlassian.seraph.auth.DefaultAuthenticator.getUserFromCookie(DefaultAuthenticator.java:430)
> com.atlassian.seraph.auth.DefaultAuthenticator.getUser(DefaultAuthenticator.java:330)
> com.atlassian.confluence.user.ConfluenceAuthenticator.getUser(ConfluenceAuthenticator.java:122)
> com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:138)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ConfluenceSecurityFilter.doFilter(ConfluenceSecurityFilter.java:25)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ThreadLocalCacheFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCacheFilter.java:25)
> com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:103)
> com.atlassian.confluence.util.AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter.doFilter(AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter.java:32)
> com.atlassian.confluence.util.AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter$SwapOnBootstrapFilter.doFilter(AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter.java:53)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.confluence.util.AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter.doFilter(AbstractBootstrapHotSwappingFilter.java:32)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:148)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:79)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:70)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.confluence.util.ClusterHeaderFilter.doFilter(ClusterHeaderFilter.java:56)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:33)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.jwt.internal.servlet.JwtAuthFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.HttpRequestStatsFilter.doFilter(HttpRequestStatsFilter.java:47)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:121)
> com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:92)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ConfluenceTimingFilter.doFilter(ConfluenceTimingFilter.java:46)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.confluence.extra.webdav.servlet.filter.ReverseProxyFilter.doFilter(ReverseProxyFilter.java:467)
> com.atlassian.confluence.extra.webdav.servlet.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:34)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:70)
> com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:58)
> com.atlassian.confluence.internal.web.filter.spring.IgnoreWebAsyncManagerFilter.doFilter(IgnoreWebAsyncManagerFilter.java:59)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.validateparam.RequestParamValidationFilter.doFilter(RequestParamValidationFilter.java:51)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.TranslationModeFilter.doFilter(TranslationModeFilter.java:39)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.confluence.plugin.servlet.filter.ActionContextCleanUp.doFilter(ActionContextCleanUp.java:72)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.LanguageExtractionFilter.doFilter(LanguageExtractionFilter.java:45)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.VCacheRequestContextFilter.lambda$doFilter$3(VCacheRequestContextFilter.java:44)
> com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.VCacheRequestContextManager.doInRequestContext(VCacheRequestContextManager.java:82)
> com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.VCacheRequestContextManager.doInRequestContext(VCacheRequestContextManager.java:72)
> com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.VCacheRequestContextFilter.doFilter(VCacheRequestContextFilter.java:43)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.confluence.util.RequestCacheThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheThreadLocalFilter.java:65)
> com.github.kristofa.brave.servlet.BraveServletFilter.doFilter(BraveServletFilter.java:59)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ZipkinTracingFilter.doFilter(ZipkinTracingFilter.java:52)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.ResponseOutputStreamFilter.doFilter(ResponseOutputStreamFilter.java:23)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.ConfluenceJohnsonFilter.doFilter(ConfluenceJohnsonFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.confluence.impl.servlet.HoldingUntilStartedFilter.doFilter(HoldingUntilStartedFilter.java:88)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.HeaderSanitisingFilter.doFilter(HeaderSanitisingFilter.java:44)
> com.atlassian.confluence.servlet.FourOhFourErrorLoggingFilter.doFilter(FourOhFourErrorLoggingFilter.java:64)
> com.atlassian.confluence.web.filter.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:46)
> com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)

**# 2**

The last time I had 'Atlassian Confluence 5.10.8' working fine was July 21 2021 on macOS 11.5.

'Confluence' stopped working after I upgraded to macOS 11.5.1 on July 26 2021. Now using macOS 11.5.2 on August 11th 2021.

```
macOS Big Sur 11.5.2 includes bug fixes for your Mac.
macOS Big Sur 11.5.1 provides important security updates and is recommended for all users.
```

Comment: It sounds as though your database server is not running.

Comment: Can't get my Database running. I can access & see the H2 data from DbVisualizer. What do you suggest is the best way to move 'localhost:8091' to 'My.atlassian.net'?

Comment: I would agree, this seems to be a DB issue.  There are few aspects you should double check.  Give this Atlassian Article a review.  https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/unable-to-start-due-to-net-sf-hibernate-exception-genericjdbcexception-cannot-open-connection-128843899.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 'Time Machine' for the past 12 months hasn't been backing:

```
atlassian-confluence-5.10.8/confluence/database
```

When I upgraded to: macOS 11.5 it started to backup a empty/null version of:

```
atlassian-confluence-5.10.8/confluence/database/h2db.h2.db.mv.db
atlassian-confluence-5.10.8/confluence/database/h2db.h2.db.mv.db.mv.db
```

Lesson learnt.